# decrypt a given ciphered text using aes algorithm

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am new to cryptography and trying to implement product key validation system. For that purpose, I am using crytopp library for AES algo. Following is my code for decrypting a ciphered text generated by AES algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cryptopp/dll.h>
#include <cryptopp/md5.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include "cryptopp/base64.h"

#define CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL

void error(std::string err)
{
    std::cout << err << "\n";
    exit(1);
}

void decrypt()
{

    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    std::string plaintext;
    std::string ciphertext;
    std::string decryptedtext;

    //std::stringstream ss;
    std::cout<< "Enter Fingerprint:  ";
    std::getline(std::cin , ciphertext);    
    std::cout << ciphertext.c_str();

    for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

    std::cout << ciphertext[i] ;

    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

    //std::cout << ciphertext[i] << " ";
    //std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
    std::cout << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) ;

    }

    memset( key, 0xACD3, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );


    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );


    std::string src;

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(ciphertext, true, 
        new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(src)
        )
        );

     std::cout << src << " ";



    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( src.c_str() ), src.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
}

void generateActivationKey(char *license_string_dect , char *activation_key){}

int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{
    char *license_string_dect , *activation_key;
    /*if(argc < 2)
      error("License Key Not Provided");*/
    decrypt();
    std::cout<< license_string_dect;
    generateActivationKey(license_string_dect , activation_key);
    std::cout<< activation_key;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is , when ciphered text is passed as a string

```
7ff8b3ea8a2b37a3d28669c9713a7b3fa2502580d5d232cee8a5733ef70ff48e9e8498a94c25ea7b04043a1fc23b1a1eb1eb2f6976270a181ca6e788090
```

I get the following error

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext'
  what():  StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size.
```

I googled for this but dint get an appropriate way to only decrypt a given ciphered text

plz help

I used this to get the FingerPrint:

```
// Key and IV setup
    //AES encryption uses a secret key of a variable length (128-bit, 196-bit or 256-   
    //bit). This key is secretly exchanged between two parties before communication   
    //begins. DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH= 16 bytes
    byte key[16]; 
    byte iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0xACD3 , CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    //
    // String and Sink setup
    //

    std::string plaintext = "vcm7878air:14522569:a12bc";
    std::string ciphertext;
    std::string decryptedtext;
    //
    // Dump Plain Text
    //
    //std::cout << "Plain Text (" << plaintext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
    //std::cout << plaintext;
    //std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //
    // Create Cipher Text
    //
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    //
    // Dump Cipher Text
    //
    std::cout << "Fingerprint is :" << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ ) {

        std::cout << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i]));
    }
```

Comment: "I googled for this". Your ciphertext is invalid, that´s it. `std::getline(std::cin , ciphertext);` is nonsense. To start with, some AES ciphertext is binary data, possibly containing `\0` . Nothing for a std::string

Comment: should I replace it with "std::string src;  cin >> src;" ??

Comment: Also, how to take this AES ciphertext (binary data) as input to the decryption program ?

Comment: How about describing what you want first? I won´t believe "decrypting binary data from the keyboard"

Comment: Do you have AES-encrypted data? Probably not,

Comment: yes we have aes-encrypted data which converted to the hex .

Comment: Can you show me some of the first bytes? If it is really encrypted stuff, how do you type it in the console input? How many bytes are there? Block mode? ...

Comment: I have added the encrypted text to my post

Comment: There are 123 hex digits. "If" this is the ciphertext (at least possible): Not a valid block length. If it should be converted back from hex first (you didn´t do that in your code): Not even full bytes. In other words, no AES-encrypted data. And if you don´t know (too) what a block mode is (i see CBC somewhere in your code), you should read some good beginners book and the lib documentation carefully before you proceed with your code.

Comment: how to convert the hex to the binary ciphertext form?

Comment: Again: Your hex stuff is neither valid AES data nor valid byte data at all. You *can´t* convert them to bytes.

Comment: Actually , I was trying to implement Licensing in my software. So for that I required to convert get the fingerprint(that is hex of my AEC Ciphertext), which I needed to decrypt in another program and generate the activation key. so, please help how to take the input as the hex of the cipher text and decrypt it .

Comment: That sounds not like a safe mechanism anyway... and Again. **This is not AES/CBC-encrypted data**. Sorry, but why can´t you understand that?

Comment: I have added to post how I have generated the Fingerprint. Fingerprint Generated here is : 62cbb81ef060514b45ce33a98dc46c5424718d8e35c26472e68bbd925f4f2a35

Comment: Got it. The problem has been solved . Anyways thanks to ur responses #deviantfan.

Comment: `CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL` is a Windows define. Are you using Windows or Linux?